Fermi level of oxide layer in MOS
At equilibrium, I know the Fermi level of metal needs to align with the Fermi level of semiconductor at equilibrium. But it is not clear to me whether the Fermi level of oxide layer needs to align with them as well at equilibrium?

Reference image:
Semiconductor Physics And Devices: Basic Principles by Donald A. Neaman

The diagram makes it clear that it is. However, the Fermi level is simply not a well-defined thing for insulators that your oxide is, and so you might as well take it as a definition. It won't matter.

It is just thermodynamics. If systems can exchange particles, at equilibrium, they need to have the same chemical potential. The Fermi level is just the chemical potential at the zero temperature limit. This makes it well defined for conductors (like metals) and insulators (like the oxide layer). Since they are in contact, the levels must therefore match as indicated by the diagram.
